# Get most common values in column of related model in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I am using Eloquent ORM and I am trying to find out what the most successful sport for a club is, based on wins in tournaments.
I have the tables `clubs`, `tournaments`, `sports` and `tournament_results`, each represented by a model (`Club`, `Tournament`, `Sports`, `TournamentResult`) with relationships. The relevant columns in my tables:
`clubs`, `tournaments`, `sports` each contain `id`, `name`
`tournament_results`: `id`, `tournament`, `club`, `place`.

Relations:
`Club` has `HasMany` with `ClubResults`
`TournamentResult` has `BelongsTo` with `Tournament` and `BelongsTo` with `Club`
`Tournament` has `HasMany` with `TournamentResults` and `BelongsTo` with `Sport`
`Sport` has `HasMany` with `Tournament`

The idea I had about getting my desired result is something like this:
`Club -> TournamentResults -> where place = 1 -> Tournaments -> get n (e.g. 3) most common sports in this set`

What I have so far is:

```
$club = Club::findOrFail($id);
$club->tournamentResults()->where('place', 1)->with('tournament.sport');
```

But now I don't know how to continue. Can someone help me in finding a solution?

Comment: Can you please add the relationships (BelongsTo, HasMany etc.) to  your question?

Comment: sure, it's updated now

Comment: This is more of a db question. I would start with building up the query in your database management software and go from there. Probably want to group on the sport name and order by sum of wins or something. This is a really hard question to answer without seeing the schema. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this relationship to your `Club` model:

```
public function wonTournaments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tournament::class, 'tournament_results')
        ->wherePivot('place', 1);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$topSport = $club->wonTournaments->groupBy('sport_id')
    ->sortByDesc(function($tournaments) {
        return $tournaments->count();
    })
    ->first()->first()->sport;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting the following exception:
`BadMethodCallException: "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortByDesc does not exist."`

Comment: Did you accidentally write `wonTournaments()` instead of `wonTournaments`?